# How to restart a qt application after crashing?

Tags: qt

Is it possible to restart a qt application after its crashing? Just like those windows service which will restart on its own. If so, how could I do it? I have tried code like this:

```
#define RESTART_CODE 1000
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int return_from_event_loop_code;
  QPointer<QApplication> app;
  QPointer<MainWindow> main_window;
  do
  {
    if(app) delete app;
    if(main_window) delete main_window;

    app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    main_window = new MainWindow(app);
    return_from_event_loop_code = app->exec();
  }
  while(return_from_event_loop_code==RESTART_CODE)

  return return_from_event_loop_code;
}
```

But it is not working...
What should I do now?

Comment: Usually the approach here is to have some sort of watchdog process. It must be independent of the crashing process, obviously

Comment: You *can* do this on Windows (search for "structured exception handling") but in general it's not a great idea -- what if your application is crashing when it starts? It could easily get stuck in a start/crash/start loop.

Comment: Your code won't work if your app crashes because of a segmentation fault...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create another qt application that runs your application.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "QProcess"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QProcess aProcess;
    QString exe = "Your process name with exact path";
    QByteArray myOut;
    while(1)
    {
        aProcess.start(exe);
        //aProcess.waitForStarted();
        //myOut = aProcess.readAllStandardOutput();
        //printf("%s",myOut.constData());
        aProcess.waitForFinished(-1);

        //QString output(aProcess.readAllStandardOutput());

        myOut = aProcess.readAllStandardOutput();
        printf("%s",myOut.constData());
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

this program will restart your app when it crashed or closed

Answer (score 0):

You can use my open source library:
https://marketplace.qt.io/products/main-loop-wdt-for-qt-qml

It is a watchdog timer for the main loop and only works if the main loop freezes (double mutex lock, infinite loop, etc.), but it would not work in an application crash.